# FIXML with QuickFix/J

Tags: java, quickfix, fix-protocol

Anyone using QuickFIX/J to process FIXML messages? As I understand quickfix/j does not support fixml out of the box yet. Any suggestions on how best to approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use QuickFIX/J to send and receive FIXML messages using tags 212/213 (XmlData). QuickFIX/J doesn't actually do anything with the XML other than provide a transport. However, you can easily bind the FIXML to Java classes using technologies like JAXB or similar. For example, you could create an abstract implementation of the `quickfix.Application` interface that would parse the FIXML received in the `quickfix.Message` and pass it to a callback method. It could also have a custom send method that would format the Java objects to FIXML (again, using something like JAXB), put the XML into tags 212/213 and then submit the message to the QuickFIX/J engine. Your FIXML-based applications would then use this subclass.

Comment: Yup, I use JAXB to create FIXML messages. Startup is a bit slow, but is sufficiently quick enough at runtime.